# Email from postfix sent to spam in gmail

Tags: gmail, postfix-mta

I have set up a POSTFIX server on my VPS and mail sent trough it is going to Spam in gmail. Here is my message:

```
Delivered-To: sgenov@gmail.com
Received: by 10.140.43.75 with SMTP id d69csp350632qga;
        Mon, 19 Jan 2015 15:29:29 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.194.89.39 with SMTP id bl7mr6149887wjb.76.1421710169272;
        Mon, 19 Jan 2015 15:29:29 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <kalina@hotelfors-bg.com>
Received: from mail.sgenov.com (mail.sgenov.com. [192.81.221.174])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id j9si29338582wjy.109.2015.01.19.15.29.28
        for <sgenov@gmail.com>;
        Mon, 19 Jan 2015 15:29:29 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of kalina@hotelfors-bg.com designates 192.81.221.174 as permitted sender) client-ip=192.81.221.174;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of kalina@hotelfors-bg.com designates 192.81.221.174 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=kalina@hotelfors-bg.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@hotelfors-bg.com
Received: by mail.sgenov.com (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id 665FB44097; Tue, 20 Jan 2015 01:29:28 +0200 (EET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=hotelfors-bg.com;
    s=default; t=1421710168;
    bh=ZOL1SsCcV0ncUnB8HJhFqzY/7ZocyZVCh5HCRSTXejY=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From;
    b=TjCDSt9mOFyoXVGu4CI7xqPxR7iHMtzeL1Nykd+t0cZBlWEH15OQQVdkDR07G4xJH
     WvKPQAFBHPVynQNYbnsRnwf4A57elvUImo77MDLZGhNGrS70fYdIjEjKAWe8BLX61G
     1GuaBLPfJYYUz6SdVjYsBPNm/io2wrWc63Sdvb1M=
To: <sgenov@gmail.com>
Subject: Hello, Stanimir
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:main.inc
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 01:29:28 +0200
From: kalina@hotelfors-bg.com
Message-ID: <f5944a29798c926bf52fda46c4197c76@hotelfors-bg.com>
X-Sender: kalina@hotelfors-bg.com
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/0.7.2

This is my new email. Please add it to contacts and reach me if you 
need anything.

Best Regards
```

As you can see, my mail server is set up with the following:

- The server has DKIM
- The server has a verified signed certificate
- SPF(TXT) is set correctly
- The server's PTR (reverse DNS) points correctly to my mail server
- All possible checking tools give a maximum result for the server (it should be trusted by everyone)

Yet, gmail sends all messages from all domains to spam. Does anyone know what the reason could be or what steps I should take? Can I contact someone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out the server had no issues at all.
Gmail seem to keep a history of the server's scores. After I set up everything correctly I had to wait for a month or so before my emails ended up outside the spam folder.

Answer (score 1):

To see if your mail server has a glaring problem that would cause other mail servers to think it's a spammer, try sending a message from your mail server to `check-auth@verifier.port25.com`. This service will do a bunch of checks, and you'll get a report back with ton of information, such whether or not your mail server's DNS is setup correctly, whether your mail server's IP is on any black lists, if you have a problem with your SPF records, etc.

Comment: as I said, such check tools tell me there is nothing wrong with my server: http://pastebin.com/s0eLVaW7

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the service mentioned above, it appears my server had a valid reverse DNS in IPv4 but not with IPv6, therefore emails would be originating from an instance without associated DNS.

This is why Gmail classified all my emails as spam.

Solution is to disable postfix IPv6 connection by setting the following in Postfix `mail.cf`

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```